# Why are unmet peer dependencies not resolved when using yarn link?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npm-link

I have 2 node packages : `foo-service` and `foo-commons`.

`foo-commons` is a dependency of `foo-service`.

While development,every time there is a change in `foo-commons`, to use them in `foo-service` I copy the compiled source from `foo-commons` to  `foo-service/node_modules/foo-commons/`:

```bash
cp -r ./foo-commons/dist ./foo-service/node_modules/foo-commons/dist
```

I recently came across a better way, which is using `yarn link`. [link](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/)

`yarn link` creates a sylink from `./foo-service/node_modules/foo-commons` to `./foo-commons/`

With this, the typescript build succeeds without manually copying the files like before.

However, when I run `foo-service`, I get a module not found error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
/foo-service/dist/server.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/foo-commons/node_modules/@typegoose/typegoose/lib/typegoose.js:6:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
```

This error occurs only when I use `yarn link`.

> The module in the error `mongoose` is an unresolved peer dependency for `foo-commons`:

```
warning " > @typegoose/typegoose@7.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "mongoose@^5.9.22".
```

Why are unmet peer dependencies not resolved when using  `yarn link`?

Comment: I go the same error using `npm link`. 
My peerDependnecies from library are not installing. When I use file:<path_to_my_tgz> everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround to this issue.

First, in project, whicch uses my library I installed `npm-install-linked`
Then I made a custom script to install:

0. project tree:

```
my_lib:
-- peerDependencies:
-----a
-----b

my_project:
----package.json:
--------file:../../my_lib_/dist/my_lib
```

1. Using `npm-install-linked` I install peer dependency in `<my_library>/node_modules` (including peer depepndencies):

```
my_project:
---node_modules
------my_lib:
---------node_modules:
------------a
------------b
```

2. I'm copying this `node_modules` to my_project root `node_modules`, skipping existing libraries:

```
cp -R -n node_modules/my_lib/node_modules/* node_modules/
```

3. And deleting `node_modules` of library to avoid build errors:

```
rm -rf node_modules/my_lib/node_modules
```

After this operations project tree:

```
my_project:
---node_modules:
-----a
-----b
-----my_lib
```

This is dirty workaround, but I didn't manage to do it better. If you know, how to do it better, let me know!